# How to put input in arrays without the need of a comma between inputs

Tags: javascript

So I'm making a program where a user input of 4 digits is needed.
in the current state the user needs to seperate the digits with commas (e.g 1,2,3,4), how can I change it so the commas aren't needed anymore?

```
function input() { 
    numbers = prompt("Put in your 4 numbers,", "1,2,3,4").split(",");
    numbers = numbers.map(Number);
    console.log(numbers);
    displaynumbers();
}
```

Comment: is it going to be always a single digit for each element ?meaning  you would never have 10, 20 , for each array element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an empty string as the delimiter argument to `split()`, each character becomes a separate element.

```js
function input() {
  var numbers = prompt("Put in your 4 numbers,", "1234").split("");
  numbers = numbers.map(Number);
  console.log(numbers);
}

input();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
numbers = prompt("Put in your 4 numbers,", "1 2 3 4").split(" ");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
numbers = prompt("Put in your 4 numbers,", "1,2,3,4").split(" ");
```

Comment: Thanks, while it technically answers the question i would prefer a way where you can just enter the whole number, so i tried just removing the space and now it works perfectly

Comment: Shall I edit my answer so you can mark it as solution?